# Orbit decomposition of the restriction of an equivariant sheaf?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, equivariant-cohomology, geometric-representation-theory, equivariant-homotopy

*All sets and groups in the question are finite.*

In order to understand equivariant sheaves better **I'm trying to prove some basic facts from Mackey theory using equivariant sheaves.** The main obstacle i've been faced with is the difficulty of keeping track of all the different equivalences.

Let $G$ be a group and $K \lt G$ a subgroup. Perhaps one of the most basic canonical equivalences is between $Sh_G(G/K)$ and $Sh_K(pt)$. This can be implemented as follows:

> Let $p: G \to pt$ and $q : G \to G/K$ be the projections. Then one has
>   the following compositions:
>
> $$Sh_K(pt) \overset{k \mapsto k^{-1}}{\longrightarrow} 
>  Sh_{K^{op}}(pt) \overset{p^*}{\to} Sh_{G \times K^{op}}(G)
>  \overset{q^{K^{op}}_*}{\to} Sh_G(G/K)$$
>
> Explanations:
>
> 1. First arrow is the inversion isomorphism from $K$ to $K^{op}$. It is obviously an equivalence.
> 2. The second arrow is the pullback which remembers the left $G$-equivariant structure coming from the fact that the projection
>      $G/K \to pt$ is left $G$-equivariant. This is an equivalence since the
>      $G$-action is free.
> 3. The third arrow is $K^{op}$-invariant sections of the pushforward along $q: G \to G/K$. This is an equivalence since the right $K^{op}$ action
>      is free.
>
> The functor in the other direction is the composition of the pseudo
>   inverses.

This is all very neat until one tries to use this equivalence to prove stuff. I'll try to explain with an example. **Suppose we wanted Mackey's induction formula.** In other words **we'd like to describe the functor** $Res^K_G \circ Ind^G_H$ in terms of other functors.

Let $p: G/H \to pt$ and $q: G/K \to pt$. In this notation the composition above admits the following description:

$$Sh_G(G/H) \overset{p_*}{\to} Sh_G(pt) \overset{Res^K_G}{\to} Sh_K(pt)$$

By commutativity of the corresponding diagram this composition is isomorphic to the composition:

$$Sh_G(G/H) \overset{Res^K_G}{\to} Sh_K(G/H) \overset{p_*}{\to}  Sh_K(pt)$$

Once one realizes that the category $Sh_K(G/H)$ splits as a direct sum  $\bigoplus_{\mathcal{O}} Sh_K(\mathcal{O})$ over all $K$-orbits in $G/H$, then the **second functor above** $p_*$ becomes easy to describe as it is just a **direct sum of induction functors.**

> **However**, consider now the following functor:
>
> $$F: Sh_K(pt) \to Sh_G(G/H) \overset{Res^K_G}{\to} Sh_K(G/H) \to
>  \bigoplus_{\mathcal{O}} Sh_K(\mathcal{O}) $$
>
> This functor obtained by composing the first functor with equivalences **seems rather
>   mysterious.**

It looks like it should be a **sum over certain restriction functors** (a fact we already know if we know about the classical mackey formula). Beyond that however **this functor is completely mysterious to me**. In order to compute it I found no other choice other than c**omposing all the functors** involved and which resulted in **a huge expression I didn't manage to decipher.**

> **How can one describe $F$ using the language of equivariant sheaves?**
>
> **How does one compute similar functors in practice?**

Of course I already know what $F$ should be from the classical Mackey formula but i'm looking for a way to "grab hold" of this functor using the language equivariant sheaves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the Mackey formula is most easily seen if you think in terms of groupoids/stacks. This idea makes sense in many situations, but for simplicity let's restrict to representations of discrete groups.

The basic idea is:

1) There is a Cartesian diagram of groupoids:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
[K\backslash G/H] @>{\widetilde{f}}>> [pt/K];\\
@V{\widetilde{g}}VV @VV{g}V \\
[pt/H] @>>{f}> [pt/G];
\end{CD}
$$
2) There is a base-change formula: $$g^\ast f_! \simeq \widetilde{f}_!\widetilde{g}^\ast : Rep(H) = Sh([pt/H]) \to Sh([pt/K]) = Rep(K)$$

3)There is a decomposition of groupoids:
$$[K\backslash G/H] \simeq \bigsqcup [pt/({}^gH \cap K)]$$

Then the Mackey formula

$$Res^G_K Ind^G_H  \simeq Ind^K_{{}^gH \cap K} Res^{{}^gH}_{{}^gH \cap K} {}^g(-): Rep(H) \to Rep(K)$$

follows immediately from these three facts (once you unravel how $[pt/({}^gH \cap K)]$ maps to $[pt/H]$ in the above decomposition).

---

**To add a bit more detail/fix notation**: Suppose $G$ is a (discrete) group acting on a set $X$. We write $[X/G]$ for the quotient/action groupoid. Note that we can write the quotient stack as a disjoint union of over orbits $$[X/G] \simeq \bigsqcup_{Gx} [pt/C_G(x)]$$ Given a groupoid $\mathcal G$ we define $$Sh(\mathcal G) = Fun(\mathcal G,Vect)$$ 
Note that $$Sh([X/G]) \simeq Sh_G(X) \simeq \bigoplus_{Gx} Rep(C_G(x))$$
(the expression for $[K\backslash G/H]$ above is a special case of this).
Given a map (functor) of groupoids $f:\mathcal G_1 \to \mathcal G_2$, we have adjoint functors
$$f_! : Sh(\mathcal G_1) \leftrightarrows Sh(\mathcal G_2): f^\ast$$
where $f^\ast$ is the obvious functor and $f_!$ is given by left Kan extension (which is a fancy way of saying sum over the fibers).

Consider the map $f:[pt/H] \to [pt/G]$ corresponding to the inclusion of a subgroup in a group. In this language the induction/restriction functors are given by
$$f_! = Ind_H^G : Rep(H) = Sh([pt/H]) \leftrightarrows Sh([pt/G]) = Rep(G): Res^G_H = f^\ast$$
Thus composites of induction and restriction functors as appear in the Mackey formula can be thought of as pushing and pulling sheaves on groupoids.